# Smooth anchor/id scrolling not working with offset for header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't get this working and I feel like I'm missing something very small and stupid but can't see what. The basic effect I'm looking for is when a link with an `id` for the `href` is clicked it smoothly scrolls down to that section of the page. But as I'm using a `position: fixed;` header some of the content is cut off, so I'm trying to use an offset of the header height.

There will be a couple of links in the header that go to actual pages, so I can't target every list item. Just the ones with (for example) `#one` as the destination. Though I could add a class to the links which use scrolling if that makes it easier.

Here's a CodePen off the code I'm using:
https://codepen.io/moy/pen/javwWx

What's stopping the jQuery from firing?

Comment: what's wrong with the code pen? If you mean you want it to scroll smoothly instead of without an animation please clarify so I can post an answer.

Comment: Yes currently when clicking a link it 'jumps' to the content. However I want it to smoothly scroll (animate) to the content.

Answer (score 1):

I added a jQuery include, view it by [clicking here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVMXqj).  I added the `.preventDefault`.

Your code:

```js
(function($) {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(e) 
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) 
    {
      
      var target = $(this.hash),
      headerHeight = $(".page-head").height() + 5; // Get fixed header height
            
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              
      if (target.length) 
      {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerHeight
        }, 500);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.page-head {
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-nav__item {
  display: inline;
}

.page-nav__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.band {
  padding: 80px;
}

#one {
  background: #eee;
}

#two {
  background: #ccc;
}

#three {
  background: #aaa;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-head">
  <nav class="page-nav">
    <ul class="page-nav__list">
      <li class="page-nav__item">
        <a href="#one" class="page-nav__link">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page-nav__item">
        <a href="#two" class="page-nav__link">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page-nav__item">
        <a href="#three" class="page-nav__link">Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="one" class="band">
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
</div>
<div id="two" class="band">
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
</div>
<div id="three" class="band">
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hmmm when I updated the CodePen that didn't seem to work either. Is there any reason why it's formatted like this `(function($) { // SCRIPT HERE })(jQuery);`. Would it be better off more like `$(document).ready(function(){ // SCRIPT HERE });`

Comment: @user1406440 created a codepen with the new code. And `$(document).ready` should work fine, but will not fix this issue.

Comment: I suppose that isn't really an issue though is it, just a different way of writing the same thing? That looks like it works great. So all I was missing was an `e` in the 2nd function and the following `e.preventDefault();` I copied your code over mine before so no idea why it didn't work but it seems to now! Just to confirm, you can't add an easing style without including the jQuery Easing Plugin can you?

Comment: @user1406440 we're not using jQuery easing plugin.  We're just using jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that's what I meant. There's no way to add a different easing method without including another plugin (which I don't want to do). Was just confirming. :)

Comment: @user1406440 Honestly, you can, it would just take a lot more work.

Comment: Yeah, sod that. I'm happy with how it behaves in the CodePen. When I add it to my site it seems to break my other scripts and the smooth scroll doesn't work, it just jumps down the page. Can you see anything wrong with it? I've added some of the other JS I have here (which works without this script included) https://codepen.io/moy/pen/Xzxdxq. There is a few other files called `theme.js` and `vendor.js` so I'll have to see if I can rip them and include them in the codepen also.

Comment: @user1406440 Works fine for me.

Comment: It should've stopped working now I've included 2 core JS files. `vendor.js` and `theme.js`. Trying to see where exactly it's falling down. Seems to throw up a `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])` error. As a bit of an aside I was going to see if there's a way of excluding the header offset when a certain link is clicked with a class.

Answer (score 0):

From anyone who either doesn't want to use JQuery, or wants a much shorter code:

```
window.scrollBy({
"behavior": "smooth",
"left": left,
"top": top
});
```

You can also write this in one line format:

```
window.scroll({top: top ,left: left ,behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Where at top and left you put the certain number of pixels that you want to scroll to.

For the `top` you can also use `element.getBoundingClientRect()` instead of specifying an exact number in pixels,as the element's exact (x,y) position might change depend on screen size or browser. That will make it a bit more responsive to smaller screens.

However I'm unaware wither this is supported on older browsers or not.

Comment: I only need to support ie11+ and the rest of the modern browsers. Then Safari/Chrome on small screen devices. That seems like a good streamline solution though. Just need to cater for an offset for the fixed header.

Comment: why do you need to change the offset of a fixed header? My website has a fixed header and this works perfectly without anything.

Comment: My mistake then! I thought if the header was 100px tall (for example) when you clicked an anchor and the content was scrolled to the top 100px would be behind the header.